# Spring JPA: ManyToMany relationship not stored in database when reuse the property to store another object

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I've got a problem with a @ManyToMany association, if a 'complex' structure of objects has to be persisted.

I've got a Java application using Spring Boot (spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.5.RELEASE) with JPA (spring boot-starter-data-jpa). As a database, I tried MySQL and H2. The effect is the same.

**Abstract 1**

I'm using a List object when creating a category and use the same List object when creating the item object.

```
Category cat1 = new Category("Cat 1", personList, null);
categoryService.create(cat1);
Item item1 = new Item("Item 1", personList, cat1);
itemService.create(item1);
```

- The category record has three person records assigned as managers in the category_managers table
- The item record has three person records assigned as persons in the item_persons table

**Abstract 2**

I'm using a List object when creating a category and reuse the category.getManager list when creating the item object.

```
Category cat2 = new Category("Cat 2", personList, null);
categoryService.create(cat2);
Item item2 = new Item("Item 2", cat2.getManagers(), cat2);
itemService.create(item2);
```

- The item has three person records assigned as persons in the item_persons table
- !!! The category has no managers assignments in the category_managers table

**Abstract 3**

Now the same procedure as in abstract 2 with an additional assignment and update:

```
Category cat3 = new Category("Cat 3", personList, null);
categoryService.create(cat3);
cat3.setManagers(personList);
categoryService.update(cat3);
Item item3 = new Item("Item 3", cat3.getManagers(), cat3);
itemService.create(item3);
```

- The category has three person records assigned as managers (see. category_managers table)
- The item has three person records assigned as persons (see. item_persons table)

**Questions**

Why are the assignments in Abstract 2 not persisted?
Didn't I take something account?
Do I misunderstand something what happens behind the scene?

This might be a special use case, but are there some topics or chapters I have to read again?

Greetings from Stuttgart

---

#### Detailed Description

**The model structure**

Person.java:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    // Constructors -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    public Person() {}
    
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    // Getters / Setters --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // ...
    
}
```

Category.java:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Person> managers;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id", updatable = false)
    private List<Item> items;
    
    // Constructors -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    public Category() {}
    
    public Category(String name, List<Person> managers, List<Item> items) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.managers = managers;
        this.items = items;
    }
    
    // Getters / Setters --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // ... 
}
```

Item.java:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Person> persons;
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;
    
    // Constructors -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    public Item() {}
    
    public Item(String name, List<Person> persons, Category category) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.persons = persons;
        this.category = category;
    }
    
    // Getters / Setters --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // ...
}
```

The property persons should contain persons assigned to a particular item.
The property category should contain an optional category assigned for multiple items. The managers of a category will be assigned to the person property of its items.

Very simple and straight forward.

**The corresponding repository interfaces and service classes**

The repository interfaces extend the JpaRepository interface.
The service classes contain methods to create, get, update and delete the records in the database.
((I'm just posting one of them))

```
@Service
public class PersonService {
    
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepo;
    
    public Person create(Person person) {
        return personRepo.save(person);
    }
    public Person get(long id) {
        return personRepo.getOne(id);
    }
    public void update(Person person) {
        personRepo.save(person);
    }
    public void delete(long id) {
        personRepo.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

**The three test cases**

And here a code to demonstrate the problem I'm facing, when creating the records in the database.
There are 3 cases.

```
@Component
public class DatabaseInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;
    @Autowired
    ItemService itemService;
    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        
        // Create persons
        Person max = personService.create(new Person("Max", "Mad"));
        Person sally = personService.create(new Person("Sally", "Silly"));
        Person bob = personService.create(new Person("Bob", "Bad"));
        List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(max, sally, bob);
        
        
        // Case 1 (this works)
        // Here we will use the personList object for both the category and the item.
        Category cat1 = new Category("Cat 1", personList, null);
        categoryService.create(cat1);
        Item item1 = new Item("Item 1", personList, cat1);
        itemService.create(item1);
        // => The category record has three person records assigned as managers (see. category_managers table)
        // => The item record has three person records assigned as persons (see. item_persons table)
        
        // Case 2 (this doesn't work)
        // Here we will use the personList object to create the category and reuse the category.getManager list to create the item.
        Category cat2 = new Category("Cat 2", personList, null);
        categoryService.create(cat2);
        Item item2 = new Item("Item 2", cat2.getManagers(), cat2);
        itemService.create(item2);
        // => The category has no managers assignments (see. category_managers table) WHY??
        // => The item has three person records assigned as persons (see. item_persons table)
        
        
        // Case 3 (workaround of case 2)
        // Here we will do the same as in case 2, but will do an extra assignment of the managers of the category
        Category cat3 = new Category("Cat 3", personList, null);
        categoryService.create(cat3);
        cat3.setManagers(personList);
        categoryService.update(cat3);
        Item item3 = new Item("Item 3", cat3.getManagers(), cat3);
        itemService.create(item3);
        // => The category has three person records assigned as managers (see. category_managers table)
        // => The item has three person records assigned as persons (see. item_persons table)
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An attempt to explain case 2**

The ArrayList object of the property `managers` of the object `cat2` turns into a PersistentBag object when calling the method `save(S entity)` of `JpaRepository` or rather `CrudRepository`. Now, this collection object does not just contains entities of `Person` objects. It seams that this object also represents the relation between the entities `Category`and `Person`.

Also to keep in mind: Java object variables points to the object in the memory heap.
Therefore, in the line `Item item2 = new Item("Item 2", cat2.getManagers(), cat2);` the `getManagers()` method hands over the reference to the real object in the memory into the constructor of the entity `Item` and not just the values.
Now, when this new entity has to be stored in the database and the PersistentBag object now represents the relationship between an item and its persons, this will be stored like that. Thus the relation will be moved.

**To explain the case 3**

The line `cat3.setManagers(personList);` just replaces the PersistentBag object with the ArrayList object.
Because the list was not changed, the update was called but there was no update of the relationships and the `getManagers()` method does not hand over a reference to the categorie's PersistentBag in the memory and keeps 'untouched'.

If we change the List object before the update, the update of the relationship will be also performed:

```
Category cat3 = new Category("Cat 3", personList);
categoryService.create(cat3);
personList.add(personService.create(new Person("Mazy", "Lazy")));
cat3.setManagers(personList);
categoryService.update(cat3);
Item item3 = new Item("Item 3", cat3.getManagers(), cat3);
itemService.create(item3);
```

**A potential nightmare**

This might have a lot of side effects.
In this simple example it is easy to debug if you know about that. But think about huge code spread over a lot of methods. And then one method uses an ArrayList from a parameter, performs changes or assigns this to other entities without knowing about the original entity or that this is a PersistentBag...

**A kind of solution**

I have to keep in mind not to simply use the return value of the `getManagers()` method only.
Additionally, I should create a new collection object.

Maybe something like:

```
Category cat2 = new Category("Cat 2", personList);
categoryService.create(cat2);
List<Person> itemPersonList = new ArrayList<>();
cat2.getManagers().forEach(itemPersonList::add);
Item item2 = new Item("Item 2", itemPersonList, cat2);
itemService.create(item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go straight to case 2. It doesn't work because it's not in a transaction. When you create an entity: `new Category("Cat 2", personList, null);` that entity is detached. You then call the transactional method `categoryService.create(cat2);` and you hand it the category. In the transaction the entity becomes persisted and trying to get the managers will work **however** once the transaction is done and the db is updated and we go back to the `run()` method **we are no longer in that transaction**. The entity cat2 is created outside of that transaction and is not updated once the transaction is done. If you want to be able to access `cat2.getManagers()` in the same method I suggest making the `run()` method transactional.

Comment: After `categoryService.create(cat2)` the records are persisted in the table "category_managers". But then, at `itemService.create(item2)`, the item record will be inserted and right after that, `delete from category_managers where category_id=?` is executed. Thus, Hibnernate "move" the realtionship. I'm wondering why and how? What's the sens of reacting like that? Because I expected no deletion here. And what about the case 3. I just do an update in between.